fail2ban iptables REJECT rules not working
I managed to setup fail2ban and monitor my mysql database logs because I am being brute force attacked through my database login. the database is in a docker container and fail2ban is on the host machine.
fail2ban is blocking the ips (XX.XXX.XXX.XXX is my test external ip)
failt2ban-client status mysqld-auth
Status for the jail: mysqld-auth
|- Filter
| |- Currently failed: 1
| |- Total failed: 415
| `- File list: /SOMEPATH/mysql/logs/error.log
`- Actions
    |- Currently banned: 7
    |- Total banned: 7
    `- Banned IP list: 94.232.45.152 38.51.181.74 38.51.180.13 186.166.141.225 38.51.159.228 94.156.71.107 XX.XXX.XXX.XXX

iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
f2b-mysqld-auth tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 multiport dports 3306

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target prot opt source destination
DOCKER-USER all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.4 tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.2 tcp dpt:9443
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.2 tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.5 tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.5 tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.3 tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.8 tcp dpt:9090
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.6 tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.7 tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.7 tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.7 tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 172.20.0.9 tcp dpt:5432

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target prot opt source destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
RETURN all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target prot opt source destination
DROP all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
DROP all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0
RETURN all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target prot opt source destination
RETURN all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

Chain f2b-mysqld-auth (1 references)
target prot opt source destination
REJECT all -- XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 94.156.71.107 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 38.51.159.228 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 186.166.141.225 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 38.51.180.13 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 38.51.181.74 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT all -- 94.232.45.152 0.0.0.0/0 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN all -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0

However, iptables rules simply don't work. I can continue trying to connect without any type of block and fail2ban log only spams "already banned"
I don't know if docker rules has something to do here

Added chain=DOCKER-USER to the jail specification, that solved the problem
